# Implementing Material Search Bar over Google Maps activity

Tags: android, sql, google-maps, android-studio

So, I am working on a mapping application (for a botanical garden) that lets me search data that I have stored in an SQL database to store names and coordinates of various plant life (I have the database set up and working).

The main issue I am running into is getting the search bar functioning properly.  I have the material search bar overlaying on my map properly, and I can search for my SQL data, however, I am using a recyclerview to display my SQL data, which overlays over my map, which makes the search functionality completely useless since it is covering the map.

I am really unsure how to either get recyclerview to collapse properly, or implement a different method so that my SQL data populates in the material search bar results, rather than just overlapping my map.  Here is my OnCreate method, where I set up the material search bar and the recycler view.  Any suggestions/help would be appreciated, since I am struggling to find guides/documentation online.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //Code used to remove/add droplist to material search bar

   recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
    layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar)findViewById(R.id.search_bar);


    database = new Database(this);

    materialSearchBar.setText("Search around The Gardens");
    materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
   // loadSuggestList();
    materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String search:suggestList)
            {
                if(search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                {
                    suggest.add(search);
                }
            }

            materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

            if(!enabled)
            {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

            startSearch(text.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {


        }

    });

    //USED IN DATABASE CLASS
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getTrees());
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[SQL data with recyclerview overlapping maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imm8a.png)

Comment: I have added a picture of what my app looks like to the bottom of the post. Click on the hypertext link.  Thanks!

Comment: use `SearchView` instead and its `setSuggestionsAdapter` method